# auval: ERROR: Class Data does not have required field:<type> == componentType

Tags: macos, audiounit, auv3

Trying to write an AUv3 on macOS. I'm getting the following error from `auval`:

```
VERIFYING CLASS INFO
ERROR: Class Data does not have required field:<type> == componentType
```

It would seem some sort of metadata is misconfigured.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

`Class Data` actually refers to `kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo`. So the error has to do with the AUv3 `fullState`, which is bridged to the AUv2 `kAudioUnitProperty_ClassInfo`. Sheesh.

The underlying issue was that my `fullState` method was not calling the superclass `fullState`.

Answer (score 0):

This workaround is working for me:

```
- (NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)getFullState {

    NSDictionary* pluginState = [data.controller getState];
    NSDictionary* superState = [super fullState];

    NSMutableDictionary* stateRes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:pluginState];
    [stateRes addEntriesFromDictionary:superState];

    return stateRes;
}
```